# Login Screen blinks with Toast

Tags: android

I created one login screen but before login screen to appear I wanted a image to flash on the screen. For this I use Toast.
But the problem is before flashing the Image Login screen appears for a while and the image flashes after that again Login Screen appears. I wants to flash the image first before any thing appears in the screen. Here is my code :

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.start));

    Toast t = new Toast(this);
    t.setView(iv);
    t.show();
    t.setDuration(5);
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use Handler Class To Hold the present LoginWindow  for few seconds , Handler Class Provides A method which can be used display image before the screens is displayed,

if is not possible with Handler method then please make use of Activity LifeCycle Methods like OnStart() etc there are lot activity methods u can use

Here is some useful code to u..

```
private Handler handler;
private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "splashScreen";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onCreate executes ...");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscr);
    handler = new Handler(); 




}


public void onResume()
{ Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onResume executes ...");
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{

    public void run()
    {
        Intent myIntent= new Intent(SplashScreen.this,TabCls.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);    
    }
}, 1000); 

super.onResume();
}


protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onStart executes ...");
}




protected void onRestart()
{
    super.onRestart();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onRestart executes ...");
}



protected void onPause()
{   
    super.onPause();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onPause executes ...");

}


protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onStop executes ...");
}    

protected void onDestroy()
{ 

    super.onDestroy();

    Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onDestroy executes ...");
}
```

}